# BindingSource not updating when user edits cell in DataGridView (Simple broken example)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

I'm new to DataGridView and getting frustrated after hours of searching and trying to understand why this simple example is not working.

The code below creates a default editable DataGridView, which is bound to a list of a simple class with DateTime, Double and string members. I'm expecting a user to enter a valid time, and then that time is set to the right public property. It doesn't even work with the string property, let alone the other two.

I've tried to investigate with various events, and the binding source just is never updated.

*(For convenience, below is a fully self-contained, functioning source example)*

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class SimpleDataGridViewBindingForm : Form
{
    private DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
    private BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

    [STAThreadAttribute()]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new SimpleDataGridViewBindingForm());
    }

    public SimpleDataGridViewBindingForm()
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Width = 400;

        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.bs.DataSource = typeof(WorkLog);
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        this.dataGridView1.CellValidated += dataGridView1_CellValidated;
        this.dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += dataGridView1_CellEndEdit;
        this.dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += dataGridView1_CallValueChanged;

        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Start", "Start");
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Length", "Length");
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Description", "Description");
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CallValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(bs.Current);    // call first, not updated here
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(bs.Current);    // not updated here also
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(bs.Current);    // and finally not updated here either
    }
}

public class WorkLog
{
    public DateTime Start;
    public double Length;
    public string Description;

    public WorkLog()
    {
        // Leave fields empty.
    }

    public WorkLog(DateTime start, double seconds, string desc)
    {
        Start = start;
        Length = seconds;
        Description = desc;
    }
}
```

I'm obviously missing something, even though this code throws no errors. Any ideas?

Comment: `public DateTime Start;` => `public DateTime Start { get; set; }`. etc. Remove `Columns.Add("Start", "Start");` etc. The default behavior is to auto generate the columns using the name and type of the object's properties. If you disable it, to provide your own definition of each Column, specify the source property/field, setting the Column's `DataPropertyName`.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi - adding get / set modifiers worked, and I deleted the manual adding of the columns. However even with doing `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false`; and removing the Add() lines, the columns were still auto-generated. Not a huge deal, just unexpected behaviour.